# How to Create a Lucene Query Searching for Phrases Using a Regular Expression?

Tags: java, regex, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate Search for the full-text search feature, but it seems Hibernate Search does not allow the search using regular expressions, so I turn to Lucene.

Now I want to create a Lucene query searching all documents containing the phrases matching the following pattern **isbn="1\d+"**, thus the documents **#1** and **#2** as follows are expected to be searched out.

1. <book isbn="101" name="abc" />
2. <book isbn="102" name="def" />
3. <book isbn="201" name="ghi" />

I have seen the **org.apache.lucene.search.RegexpQuery.RegexpQuery(Term)** method, but it only accepts terms using the regular expression instead of phrases. A statement like `luceneQuery = new RegexpQuery(new Term("content", "isbn=\"1\d+\""));` does not work.

Could you have a solution to solve this for me? Thanks.